# Powershell invoke executable with arguments

Tags: powershell

Yes, I know, there are dozens of posts for this with virtually the same title; however, I cannot seem to get anything to work.

I am simply trying to call an executable that has arguments/switches from within a Powershell script. There are ~50 different executables I need to run for a script with varying commands and parameter lists.  I cannot figure out how to run even to most Mickey Mouse examples.  If I can find a solution to run the following, I can probably extrapolate the solution to fit my needs.

> - rmdir "C:\SomePath" /S /Q
> - dir /s /b

I have tried many, MANY posted solutions and none of them work [for me] and virtually all of them yield the same errors.  For the examples above, I usually get one of the following:

> - "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/S'."
>     or
> - "Cannot find path 'D:\s' because it does not exist."

I have tried various prescribed solutions using ampersand call operator, splitting arguments, escaping quotes, Invoke-Process, Start-Process, Invoke-Expression, etc. and none will even run without error.

Ironically, I am able to run some commands with switches without any errors.  E.g., running the following works without any errors without escaping/wrapping/encapsulating--just including the line in the script.  You will notice it has switches and those switches have slashes.

> - taskkill /f /im MyTask

Also, both of the following work (notice slash versus non-slash):

> - ping -n 3 -4 -l 64 yahoo.com
> - ping /n 3 /4 /l 64 yahoo.com

So, it appears that slashes are not the issue.  I just don't know why the above examples do not work.

Please, I am ***NOT*** looking for a Powershell equivalent for the above examples.  I.e., I am not looking for a Get-ChildItem solution for dir or Remove-Item solution for rmdir.  I am ***literally*** looking at how to call an executable in Powershell that has arguments; and, specifically, using those examples.  It would also be nice to know why the dir/rmdir examples do not work while the taskkill and ping do.

Thank you in advance for your response.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: almost all cmd commands can be used in PowerShell without any "special" invocation, just run the cmd command as you would in cmd. I think you were probably running into the quotes / double quotes problem, but we can't say for sure when you don't post any example of how you ran your commands, so please edit your question and add some examples

Comment: You are reading the examples.  All of the commands above were added to the script as-is.  It was only after they failed that I tried all of the referenced solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`dir` is not an executable.** It is a built-in shell command – both PowerShell and Cmd have their own internal commands named 'dir' and they accept completely different arguments. (The PowerShell version is actually an alias for Get-ChildItem and expects standard PS-style arguments.)

To call a Cmd built-in from PowerShell, run it through `cmd.exe /c`:

```
cmd /c rd/s/q C:\SomePath
cmd /c "dir /s /b"
```

(Or implement the exact same functionality using PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem`.)

Similarly, to call a PowerShell built-in from Cmd, you would call powershell.exe:

```
powershell -Command "gci -recurse C:\SomePath | % {echo $_.Name}"
```

Your other examples are standalone executables (taskkill.exe and ping.exe) so their behavior does not differ between shells.

Comment: That is it.  Thanks for your response.  It resolved my issues.